# Does a shiny pokemon stay shiny after evolution?

Tags: pokemon-series

I recently encountered a shiny Golbat which I would love to evolve into a Crobat. My only worry is **will evolution cancel out the shiny attribute?** I have never caught a shiny before, except for the red Gyarados in Heart Gold / Soul Silver, and since he doesn't evolve anymore I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: I don't believe so, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: "Shiny" pokemons? What's dat? (I left after the old gold & silver versions.)

Comment: @Lysarion It's literally a shinier version of that pokemon.

Comment: @Lysarion - It's an extremely rare occurence. When encountering a pokemon in the wild, there is a 1:2^13 chance of it being shiny.

Comment: @Lysarion - There were shinies in Gold and Silver.

Comment: @Lysarion - Do you remember the Red Gyarados? That was a guaranteed shiny encounter.

Comment: @KOVIKO Not really. Shiny means reflecting light, and it's not about bright. The name in spanish describes it best: variocolor (*of another color*)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, a shiny pokemon will remain shiny after evolution.

> Upon evolution, a Pokémon will retain its Shiny status. A Shiny
>   Charmander, if leveled up, will eventually become a Shiny Charmeleon
>   and then a Shiny Charizard, just as a regular Charmander will become a
>   regular Charmeleon and then a regular Charizard. This is due to the
>   status being determined by values inherent to the Pokémon.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny)

Comment: Perhaps you should quote the part of the webpage that states that? For one thing, it's a really long page, and it's also best practice to avoid potential link rotting.

Comment: Sure, but I wasn't including that as the answer, just showing that I did in fact have a legitimate source, and wasn't just pulling it out of my... head. But, if it'll make you happy...

Answer (score 2):

If a shiny pokemon evolves, it will stay shiny. For example, if you have a shiny sentret and evolve it into furret, it will stay shiny. I am certain because my shiny azurill evolved into marill and azumarril, still being shiny.